# C++ for loop that reverses the digits 10 - 99

Tags: c++

I am trying to write code that will list and reverse all digit pairs from 01 - 99. 01-09 is  easy enough since you just have to multiply it by 10. I also know at least one way to reverse a given digit, I just don't know how to properly use it with a for loop.

This is what I have so far.

```
 for ( int num99 =1 ; num99 > 0 && num99 < 100; num99 = num99+1)
            {
                if (num99 <10){
                    temp99 = num99 * 10;
                    cout << temp99 << endl;
                }
                else {
                    while (num99 != 0) {
                        remainder99 = num99 % 10;
                        reverse99 = (reverse99 * 10) + remainder99;
                        num99 = num99 / 10;
                    }
                    cout << reverse99 << endl;
                }
            }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is the itended output (99, 89, 79, ...09, 98, 97...?) and what do you currently get with your code?

Comment: For a number like 47, you can use the expressions `47/10` → 4 and `47%10` → 7 to get the first and last digits. Then just output last digit first.

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. (There are numerous ways to do what you're evidently trying, in addition to the one sketched in my comment.)

Comment: Try compiling with warnings on (`-Wall -Wextra` for *gcc* and *clang*) and fixing any warnings you get. Then, can you explain, in your own words, what is the inner (while) loop doing, why is it there?

Comment: Also, read up what is MCVE and produce one for this question. This code does not compile. It may possibly have Undefined Behavior of using uninitialized variables, hard to say without seeing the entire code.

Comment: `for (value=1; value<100; value++) result = (value % 10)*10 + (value / 10);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reinitialize the values of `remainder99, reverse99, temp99, num99` after you have used them.
You also have to prepend 0 to the result, when you reverse 10, 20, 30 etc...  to get 01, 02, 03 etc...
After making the necessary changes, your program will look like this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{  
  int remainder99 = 0;
  int reverse99 = 0;
  int temp99 = 0;  

  for ( int num99 =1 ; num99 > 0 && num99 < 100; num99 = num99+1)
    {
        if (num99 <10){
            temp99 = num99 * 10;
            cout << temp99 << endl;
        }
        else {
            temp99 = num99;
            while (num99 != 0) {
                remainder99 = num99 % 10;
                reverse99 = (reverse99 * 10) + remainder99;
                num99 = num99 / 10;
            }
            if(reverse99 < 10) cout << 0;
            cout << reverse99 << endl;
            reverse99 = 0;
            remainder99 = 0;
            num99 = temp99;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
01
11
21
31
41
51
61
71
81
91
02
12
22
32
42
52
62
72
82
92
03
13
23
33
43
53
63
73
83
93
04
14
24
34
44
54
64
74
84
94
05
15
25
35
45
55
65
75
85
95
06
16
26
36
46
56
66
76
86
96
07
17
27
37
47
57
67
77
87
97
08
18
28
38
48
58
68
78
88
98
09
19
29
39
49
59
69
79
89
99
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help everyone!

Comment: You can accept the answer so that people will know that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is trying to operate over the loop variable, which causes unexpected results. Instead, separate your loop variable and your `num99` variable like this:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        int num99 = i;

        if (num99 < 10) {
            temp99 = num99 * 10;
            cout << temp99 << endl;
        } else {
            remainder99 = num99 % 10;
            num99 = num99 / 10;
            if (remainder99 == 0) {
                cout<<"0"<<num99<<endl;
            } else {
                reverse99 = remainder99 * 10 + num99;
                cout << reverse99 << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also taken the liberty of assuming that when you reverse the two digit numbers like `10`, `20`, etc, you want the output to be `01`, `02`, like that, if that is not what is expected by you, you can remove the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issues with mentioned code like

1. Here `reverse99 * 10` what is initial value of `reverse99` ? Assign it as `0`.
2. Here `num99 = num99 / 10;` you are modifying original `num99` which outer loop variable, instead of this assign `num99` to some temporary variable & do operation with that temporary variable.

Sample Code

```
int main(void) {
  int temp99 = 0,remainder99 = 0, reverse99 = 0/* must initialize with 0 */ ;
  for ( int num99 =1 ; num99 > 0 && num99 < 100; num99 += 1) {
    if (num99 <10){
      temp99 = num99 * 10; 
      std::cout << num99 << std::endl;
    }
    else {
      reverse99 = 0;/*make it as 0 again for every iteration */
      temp99 = num99; /* assign loop variable to temp99 & do the operation with that */
      while (temp99 != 0) {
        remainder99 = temp99 % 10;
        reverse99 = (reverse99 * 10) + remainder99;
        temp99 /= 10;
      }
      std::cout << reverse99 << std::endl;

    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: From his question I think he is talking two digit numbers so 9 is really 09 and the reverse of 9 is therefore 90.

Answer (score 0):

A C++11 oriented solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> in(99);
    std::iota(in.begin(), in.end(), 1);

    std::for_each(in.begin(), in.end(), [](int& i)
    {
        i = (i % 10)*10 + (i / 10);
    }
    );

    for (const auto& val : in)
    {
        std::string out = std::to_string(in);
        if (out.size() == 1)
        {
            out = '0' + out;
        }
        std::cout << out << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```